# The import org.mockito.Mock cannot be found

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle

I am experiencing a problem I hope you can help with.

I want to use Mockito in my Spring Boot w/Gradle project, but STS cannot resolve the dependancy.

I have the following in my `build.gradle` file;

```
repositories { jcenter() }
dependencies { testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+') }
```

When I do a `./gradlew --info build` I can see that it is resolving Mockito:

```
Resolved versions: {org.mockito:mockito-core=1.+}
Using version '1.+' for dependency 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
Using version '1.+' for dependency 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

After a `./gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse` it is in my STS Project's Build Path

[image: In Build Path]

My Code File is showing the following message:

[image: cannot resolve Mockito]

I have another project, setup in exactly the same way and it is working fine.

Please help me out guys, Luke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use with  a static import:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;   ...or...
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

Comment: @lukegjpotter see my answer.

Comment: Thank you, @Harshad. You are both a life saver and a GitHub commit streak saver.

Comment: @lukegjpotter gald to help you.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Harshad's response, you can make your life easier and let Eclipse handle the static imports by adding the mockito methods to your favorite imports 
[image]

This will then result in the following hint:
[image]

Comment: For this, you need to click on `New Type` => `Browse` and enter the package name e.g. `org.mockito`.

Answer (score 2):

Add the dependencies with `androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.28.2"` instead of the `testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.28.2"`

The dependencies added with `androidTestImplementation` will be available in:

- `app\src\androidTest`

The dependencies added with `testImplementation` will only be available in the android `test` folder available on:

- `app\src\test`

Answer (score 0):

Add `testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0')` dependency to build.gradle and then download sources works for me in Netbeans IDE. Version number can be different.